# Google Cloud Platform - Failed to load project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I'm having some strange behaivour, something I haven't seen before. I have an old Spreadsheet that had an attached apps script. Suddendly it's exploding! I'm trying to improve it, but I've come to the realization that somehow this script doesn't have a GCP project attached to it.

No way to activate advanced services or stack driver console 
[image: no GCP?!]
[image: 403 error?]

Since I don't really have any GCP control from the script I can't bind it to a new GCP project!

Any ideas?

//Edit: I cannot move or replicate the script on another sheet, to many users and constraints

Comment: "Suddendly it's exploding! I'm trying to improve it, but I've come to the realization that somehow this script doesn't have a GCP project attached to it." no idea what you're even talking about

Comment: The apps scripts project doesn't have  a GCP project behind it